# access controller action variables to zf2 layout

Tags: zend-framework2

I have created two layouts: one for the login page and another for the rest of the site. After login I want to pass variables from login controller to zf2 layout, but not able to access.

How can i access the variables in layout created in a controller action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ways to do that in your controller:

#### Using view model

```
$viewmodel = new ViewModel();
$viewmodel->setVariable('myvar', $myvar);
return $viewmodel;
```

#### Using layout()

```
$this->layout()->myvar = $myvar;
```

## Into your view script

```
<?php echo $this->myvar; ?>
```