# How to get Zend Framework 2 action in a view

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2 I would like to get the current action from the layout html file, to know which menu is active (for css purposes).
Has anybody information how can I do it?
I tried many possible solutions but all of the was useless.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into stack overflow

- [Zend Framework 2 Get controller name from layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306573/zend-framework-2-get-controller-name-from-layout/17315222#17315222)
- [access controller action variables to zf2 layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665010/access-contoller-action-variables-to-zf2-layout/16665322#16665322)

you should put your already tested code too.

Comment: The second option is working. To use it permanently I combined it with overidden onDispatch method shown in next answer.

Comment: So the solution based on Remi's second link: `public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) {
        $this->layout()->action = $this->params("action");
        return parent::onDispatch($e);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

So based on Remi's second link the full code is:

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e) {
    $this->layout()->action = $this->params("action");
    return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```

With this always can be send any data for layout. But only for layout.